# Python equivalent to MATLAB's sortrows function

Tags: python, matlab, sorting

I have a matrix `a` of size 300x5. The matlab command to perform some operation is
`sortrows(a, [5 -2 4])`

I am trying to implement this in Python.

I have tried this out

```
idx = np.lexsort((a[:,3],a[:,1][::-1],a[:,4]))
a= a[idx]
```

But it isn't working as required (ie output not similar to that of Matlab)

Comment: You are translating index 5 into 3, 2 into 1, and 4 into 4. I guess if you consistently picked the right columns, your code might work correctly.

Comment: When I read the documentation it seems that this is translating 5 into 4, 2 into 1 and 4 into 3 and this is what I want